# Cannot SSH to system after releasing elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I had an EC2 instance with elastic IP on AWS. Because of the cost, I disassociated elastic IP from the instance. Now, my instance got a new IP.

But now I cannot SSH into my instance. Most probably my apache has not started because of which my website is also not accessible.

I tried to re-associate the elastic IP we well as restart the instance but of no use.

Why can I not SSH into my EC2 instance?

Comment: Note that an elastic IP only costs you money when it is **not** associated with a running instance.  Currently it costs $.05 an hour for disassociated EIPs.

Comment: Misread the cost - it is actually $.005 an hour, which is less than $4/month.

Answer (score 1):

when you disassociate the EIP the instance gets a new/different public IP that you need to know to ssh in or do http requests to apache. Find the new IP in your ec2 console -> instances -> description -> Public IP.

Comment: Thanks BretzL, yes I got a new IP address. I tried to SSH with this new IP but I got connection refused.

Comment: do you have the exact error from ssh? Removed the old IP from known hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Apache has no impact on SSH-ing into your system.

You need to change the IP you are connecting to in your ssh client or cmd line.  The new IP can be found in the ec2 console in Instances in the Public IP column.

Additionally, the elastic IP does not cost money if it is attached to a running instance. "While your instance is running, you are not charged for one Elastic IP address associated with the instance, but you are charged for any additional Elastic IP addresses associated with the instance." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html